# Checking out remote branch using libgit2sharp

Tags: git, github, commit, libgit2sharp

Consider the following, I have two branches on github: master and dev. I have a local repository that's a clone of and is pointing to the remote master but I'd like to switch it to the dev branch so that any changes I make will be committed to dev instead of master. What steps would be required to do that? I've tried multiple ways, but they never seem to work and it always commits to master. Please explain simply as I'm still new to Git and libgit2sharp so I'm still trying to wrap my head around it.

Edit: I'm using the libgit2sharp library to issue the git commands, not the Git shell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your dev branch exists then:

```
git checkout dev
```

If your dev branch does not yet exist, then you will need to create it and then switch to it with:

```
git checkout -b dev
```

Using libgit2sharp, there is no way to do a `git checkout -b` (that I know of), so you would need to use [`CreateBranch`](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/wiki/git-branch#creating-a-branch-pointing-at-the-current-head) 
to create a branch and then [`Checkout`](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/wiki/git-checkout) to perform a checkout of the branch.

The code would look like this:

```
private void GetOrCreateThenCheckoutBranch(string myPath, string branchName)
{
    // NOTE: This code is for demo purposes only.  It is a bad idea
    // to create code that couples multiple functions/actions together

    using (var repo = new Repository("path/to/your/repo"))
    {
        var devBranch = repo.Branches["dev"];

        if (branch == null)
        {
            // Repository returns null object when branch does not exist
            // so, create a new, LOCAL branch
            repo.CreateBranch("dev");   // Or repo.Branches.Add("dev", "HEAD");
            devBranch = repo.Branches["dev"];

            // You will need more code _here_ if you want to synchronize/set 
            // an upstream branch...
        }

        // Now, checkout the branch
        Branch currentBranch = Commands.Checkout(repo , devBranch);

        // Do more stuff...
}
```

Git is a distributed version control system.  When you make changes, you are making changes in the branch in your local copy of the repository.  Once you have made your changes locally, you will then need to

- add and commit the changes locally (possibly push them up to the
  remote repository, if you have a mapped, remote branch of the same name)
- merge the changes back into master
- push the changes up to the remote master repository (typically origin/master).

If the remote branch does not allow anyone to do a merge, you will need to issue a [pull request](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-pull-request/).

Comment: Hmm, but is there a libgit2sharp equivalent to checkout -b?

Comment: My understanding (perhaps incorrect) was that you were/are working on the libgit2sharp project on GitHub, and that you were using git.  Are you using libgit2sharp to issue the git commands?

Comment: Yes I am. I'm sorry if that wasn't very clear. I'm using libgit2sharp to issue git commands

Comment: OK.  In that case, I don't know of a way to do a `git checkout -b`.  So you would need to use [`git-branch`](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/wiki/git-branch#creating-a-branch-pointing-at-the-current-head) to create a branch and then [`git-checkout`](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/wiki/git-checkout) to perform a checkout of the branch.

Comment: I updated my answer for you to make it more comprehensive and tailored for libgit2sharp.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Appreciated. I was doing the checkout without branching first. Would I need to point it to an empty local directory before branching or would my existing local directory be ok?

Comment: Good question.  Git stores everything all in one place.  So, when you clone your respository, master and dev are both in the same folder.  Think of them as different aspects of the same repository.  

So you don't need two folders.  (That is one for master and one for dev.)

Comment: You don't want `git checkout -b` here, you just want `git checkout <branch>`.  If you use `git checkout -b` that will create a new branch from the current branch, which does _not_ track the remote branch.  But whichever mechanism you're trying to do, yes, LibGit2Sharp can do that.

Answer (score 8):

When you do not yet have a local branch named `dev`, but your remote *does* have a `dev` branch, then running `git checkout dev` will create a new `dev` branch locally, set up the remote tracking information and then switch to the newly created branch.  You can emulate this behavior in LibGit2Sharp.

To create a local branch `dev` that tracks the remote `dev` branch (`refs/remotes/origin/dev`), first locate the remote branch:

```
Branch trackedBranch = repo.Branches["origin/dev"];
```

Then create a new local branch called `dev` that points to the same commit as the `origin/dev` branch:

```
Branch localBranch = repo.CreateBranch("dev", trackedBranch.Tip);
```

Then set up the tracking between the local and remote branches:

```
repo.Branches.Update(localBranch, b => b.UpstreamBranch = "refs/heads/dev");
```

Finally, switch to the new branch:

```
LibGit2Sharp.Commands.Checkout(repo, "dev");
```

Comment: Shouldn't you also set the `Remote` in the `repo.Branches.Update(...)` part to really emulate a `git checkout <branch>` ?

Comment: Setting the `UpstreamBranch` property sets both the `remote` and the `merge` configuration option.

Comment: Just double-checked the code on master, but I think it does not. Setting the `TrackedBranch` *does* set both the `remote` and the `merge` config option, but I think setting the `UpstreamBranch` directly only sets the `remote` config option.

Comment: Just tested. you need to set the remote like this:
repo.Branches.Update(localBranch, b => b.Remote = "origin");